# Can SymPy understand variables that are indexed by a summation index?

Tags: sympy

I have an equation that is of the form (in LaTeX syntax):

```
\sum_{k=0}^{K-1} a_k = 0
```

`a_k` is "a subscript k", one of a list of variables that I'm setting up a system of linear equations in. I would like to be able to express this equation to SymPy in as compact of a way as possible. It seems like I would want to use its `Sum()` function to express the summation, but I'm not sure how to tell it that `on term k in the sum, a_k refers to the k-th symbol`.

Is this possible, for instance if I set up a list of symbols like this?

```
a = [sympy.symbols('a' + str(i)) for i in xrange(K)]
```

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean something like this?

```
In [1]: a = IndexedBase("a")

In [2]: Sum(a[k], (k, 0, K-1))
Out[2]: 
K - 1     
 ___      
 ╲        
  ╲   a[k]
  ╱       
 ╱        
 ‾‾‾      
k = 0
```

`IndexedBase` are supposed to create a variable that needs to specify an index each time it is used. If the indices are different, the variables should be considered different (e.g. `a[k]` vs `a[j]`).

In case your summation has known limits (i.e. non literal), you may expand it:

```
In [3]: Sum(a[k], (k, 0, 10))
Out[3]: 
  10      
 ___      
 ╲        
  ╲   a[k]
  ╱       
 ╱        
 ‾‾‾      
k = 0     

In [4]: Sum(a[k], (k, 0, 10)).doit()
Out[4]: a[0] + a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + a[4] + a[5] + a[6] + a[7] + a[8] + a[9] + a[10]
```

Unfortunately, not all of SymPy's algorithms support `IndexedBase` objects completely. Replacement with a `Symbol` is advised in such cases.